# Ionic Menu Event Listeners

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an ionic app with a side menu, I want to animate the list items on the side menu when it is toggled open using animate.css.  To do this when the menu is opened I add a css class to the menu items.  When the menu is closed I remove the class.

I did some research and found some event listeners that were added to ionic which I tried:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" class="sidemenu-header" (ionOpen)="toggleMenuState()" (ionClose)="toggleMenuState()">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <img src="./assets/imgs/sidebar-header-icon.png" class="icon"/>
      <ion-title>
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content class="sidemenu-content" (click)="toggleMenuState()">
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" 
      [ngClass]="{'test-class': isMenuOpen === true}">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Now when the menu is opened the class get's added however when I click outside the menu to close the it the classes do not get removed.

How do I do this?

Comment: Could you please create a minimal example at https://stackblitz.com so we can play with it?